# Remove Download Option from CloudFront URLs accessible through Browser or set Request Headers for GetObject url access

Tags: header, amazon-cloudfront, restriction

How can we remove the download option for any video/mp4 when we try to access signed url generated in cloudFront ?

Is there a way to set Request Headers in GetObject Request either through Bucket Policy update or Lambda@Edge to pre-check if the header is present in the url get request or not before allowing the user to access the url in browser ?